# How do I get this to work PHP form sender

Tags: php, forms, sender

Can anyone see what is wrong with my PHP form sender code:??

My code is listed below - the form always says no matter what, incorrect email address. Thus, it is broken. Much appreciate your help!

```
$to = "joinrendezvous@gmail.com";
$from = "mail@example.com";

$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";

$subject = "New subscription";
$body = "New user subscription: " . $_POST['email'];


if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f " . $from)) {
        echo 'Alright ! You will be notified on <b>  ' . $_POST['email'] . '</b> :)';
    }
    else {
        echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';  
    }
}
else {
    echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';  
}
```

Comment: BY THE WAY... this is my HTML code:

Comment: <form action="form_sender.php" method="post">  
                        
                        <div class="seven columns">
                
                                <input name="email" class="email" type="text" placeholder="ENTER YOUR E-MAIL">
                        
                        </div>

Answer (score 0):

What is the incorrect e-mail & what are you trying to do?

Look at this:

```
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f " . $from)) {
```

While the `if` is checking for `$_POST['email']`, the `mail` command is using `$to` as the variable. Huh? Maybe your code should be:

```
if (filter_var($to, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f " . $from)) {
        echo 'Alright ! You will be notified on <b>  ' . $to . '</b> :)';
    }
    else {
        echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $to . ')';  
    }
}
else {
    echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $to . ')';  
}
```

But then again, why are you doing this via a form if you are not going to use the `$_POST` form variables?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the $_POST['email']. echo it out so you could see if the $_POST['email'] is in correct format for email, because the filter_var checks that..